# retrieve subdomain as a get variable

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

Hi guys I'm setting up mywebapplication to give unique urls for users such as uniquename.mysite.com, anotheuniqname.mysite.com etc.

I want to be able to in a php script grab the subdomain part of the url. Would be nice if I can get it as a GET variable - I think it can be done with htaccess. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
$subdomain = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '.'));
```

To make sure there's a valid subdomain:

```
$urlExplode = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

if (count($urlExplode) > 2 && $urlExplode[0] !== 'www') {

    $subdomain = $urlExplode[0];

}
else {
    // treat as www.mysite.com or mysite.com
}
```

Comment: Nice but how would I check to make sure the url has a subdomain ? if he just types in mysite.com without a subdomain the code would return mysite as though it were a subdomain.

Comment: See my edit above. Checks theres are more than 2 dots and that the first term isn't www.

Answer (score 2):

I would try this (at the beginning of your PHP code):

```
$_GET['subdomain'] = substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '.'));
```

Explanation: `strrpos` find the last occurance of '.' in the accessed domain, `substr` then returns the string up to this position. I assigned the return value to a `$_GET` var so you can use it as if it were a normal URL-parameter.

Comment: For Sample Sub Domain: 'foo.some-domain.com', the code you presented above would return 'foo.some-domain'. I think you were expecting 'foo'.

Comment: This approach is less reliable when working only with top level domains (ie - 'some-domain.com').  Using the code above on the sample domain: 'some-domain.com', would result in 'some-domain'.

You could incorporate the following 2 lines to evaluate whether or not a subdomain exists:
$subdomain = '';

`if(substr_count($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '.') > 1) {
  $subdomain = substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 0,strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"."));
 }`

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your bootstrap file:

```
$tmp = explode(".", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], 2);
$_GET["subdomain"] = $tmp[0];
```

Comment: I wonder whether you could write `list($_GET['subdomain']) = explode(".", $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], 2);` But still, the substr + strpos variant is better ;)

Comment: @nikic you cannot, as explode returns more, than just the subdomain, also returnes the rest of the string, so you'll need some temporary variable using this method anyway

Comment: your answer assumes he has a bootstrap file in the first place

Comment: @JM4 - if he has users, he probably has a database. If he has a database, he probably connects in a single file. That's good enough for a bootstrap file.

Answer (score 1):

Ali - don't you mean a `$_SERVER` variable as `$_GET` would be related to the querystring ??

if so, then you could try:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

jim

[edit] - see http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/05/useful-server-variables-php.html for a few examples that may help

Comment: Actually I'm set up my web application to be accessed from set urls as users set up. Like mysite.wordpress.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `mod_rewrite` in your `.htaccess` file, you could do something like this (assuming your script is `index.php` in this example):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Prevent people from going to to index.php directly and spoofing the
# subdomain value, since this may not be a desirable action
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\sindex\.php.*(\?|&)subdomain=
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}         ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?subdomain=%1
```

Comment: If you had that in your `httpd.conf` file and not an `.htaccess` file, then I don't see why PHP would be more efficient. Since PHP is interpreted, and most web servers are compiled, I think `mod_rewrite` would be more efficient.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with you. Assuming he were to do it in a per-directory context though (based on his wording), and given that he's going to be invoking the PHP script either way, I'm not sure whether `mod_rewrite`'s expression compiling and the internal redirection it's forced to make in that phase are going to be quicker than just processing the variables in the script. I imagine the difference isn't very significant anyway.

Comment: your code contains errors: RewriteCond: cannot compile regular expression '^[A-Z]+\\sindex\\.php.*(?|&)subdomain='

Comment: @JM4 Yep, there was another issue too. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something along the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[a-z0-9-]+\.yoursite\.com$
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ index.php [L]
```

you could then get the subdomain using

```
<?php

preg_match('/^http:\/\/([a-z0-9-]+)\.yoursite.com$', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $matches);

$_GET['username'] = $matches[1];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This little function will simply get your " `www.website.com` " or in your case " `subdomain.website.com` ", and then split it up in 3 parts `( 0=>"www", 1=>"website", 2=>"com" )`, and then return value `1`, which is either " `www` " or your subdomain name.

```
function isSubdomain()
{
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $host = explode('.',$host);
    $host = (is_array($host)?$host[0]:$host);
    return $host;
}
```

Exaple: If your website is " `admin.website.com` ", you will receive "`admin`".