# Subdomains using same back-end with different CSS

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

I have created multiple subdomains for my website...

Main site:
example.com

Subdomains:
name1.example.com
name2.example.com
name3.example.com
name4.example.com

The subdomains are going to be using the same php and html back end as the main site.  The only difference will be the CSS.

I was thinking about possibly just requiring the files I need in the documents for each subdomain so I can do quick and easy updates across the board.

I'm not sure that this is the best way to handle this, but completely cloning the site over and over seems redundant.  Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Simply use an absolute path for your CSS files on every subdomain `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//example.com/css/global_styles.css">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better way, yes. This is how I would approach the situation.

Assume you have this file tree for your front-end;

```
- /
 - [all-backend related files]
 - sites/
 |- default/
   |- pages/
     |- index/
       | - index.css
 |- name1/
   |- pages/
     |- index/
       | - index.css
 |- name2/
   | - pages/
      | - index/
        | - index.css
```

Your PHP would then look something like;

```
function isSubdomain() {
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/15852997/3000179
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $host = explode('.',$host);
    $host = (is_array($host)?$host[0]:$host);
    return $host;
}

//Assume we are on the site1.domain.com/index
//Assume we are on your template file, and we're at the
//<head> tags within your page
if( file_exists(__DIR__ .'/'. isSubdomain() .'/pages/index/index.css') ) {
   echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"".  __DIR__ ."/". isSubdomain() ."/pages/index/index.css\">";
} else {
   echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"".  __DIR__ ."/default/pages/index/index.css\">";
}
```

Then, point all your sub-domains to have have `DocumentRoot` or `/`, and let PHP load the relevant CSS files.

Comment: Great to hear @Urbo425!

Answer (score 0):

I have a java background but I'm sure there's something similar in php where you can put all the css files for each subdomain in a separate file. Then in your php code, check the url of the request and include the file that contains the css for that subdomain